# How to make subform display data according to combobox selection?

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox

I'm trying to bind multiple tables together and have a subform display data based on my combobox (ID name = CbproductName) selection in a form named Form2. I'm using Ms office Access.

This is the query

```
SELECT Employee.EmpName, Employee.EmpCode, Employee.CompanyID, Employee.DeptID,
       Employee.ComputerID, Software.ProductName 
  FROM Software
       INNER JOIN (
             (
              Computer INNER JOIN Employee ON Computer.CompID = Employee.ComputerID) 
              INNER JOIN Application ON Computer.ComputerName=Application.[A-ComputerID]
             )
       ON Software.ID = Application.SoftwareID 
 WHERE Application.SoftwareID = Form2.CbProductName;
```

However it keeps prompting me to enter the parameter value when i run the form, and it doesn't display the result of the entered value. it also doesn't change according to the combobox selection.
Can someone point me at a direction to get it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a query, reference a form by its name as a member of the `Forms` collection.  And then reference the value of a control on that form using the control name.  It should look like this pattern:

```
Forms!FormName!ControlName
```

In your query, change the `Where` clause to this:

```
WHERE Application.SoftwareID = Forms!Form2!CbProductName;
```

Then make sure to refresh that query in after update event of `CbProductName`.  You indicated the query is used as the record source for a subform, so assuming the subform control is on the same form as the combo box, try this as the after update procedure:

```
Private Sub CbProductName_AfterUpdate()
    Me!SubformControlName.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

Beware, the subform control name may not be the same as the name of the form it contains.  Make sure you use the name of the *control*.

Comment: Wow thank you very much. It totally solve my issue.
This really lighten up my workload. :D (Y)